# How can you create an ASP.Net 2.0 web service that consumes and produces JSON objects?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, web-services, json

I would like create a web service in ASP.Net 2.0 that will supports JSON.  Is there a way to do this without WCF and .Net 3.5?  Can anyone point me to a good article or sample code?

**Clarification**

I need direction on what is the best method, using the .Net 2.0 framework, to communicate JSON objects to a client.  Is it possible to do this without serializing the object to a string and then deserializing on the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with standard 2.0 without serialization.

Answer (score 2):

use JayRock!

JayRock will work with .net 2.0

http://jayrock.berlios.de/

Answer (score 1):

WCF is great, but requires .net 3.5.

Check out this article on MSDN that describes quite a bit about JSON and asp.net from an introductory level.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299886.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize WCF for your website, The WCF JSON endpoint can even generate javascript client proxy for the service.

Check out this post

[REST / SOAP endpoints for a WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186631/rest-soap-endpoints-for-a-wcf-service#186695)

A download sample can be found

http://www.codemeit.com/wcf/wcf-restful-pox-json-and-soap-coexist.html

Answer (score 0):

I found [this API](http://www.codeplex.com/Json) for LINQ to JSON very helpful and easy.

Comment: Thanks - I use JSON.Net currently.  What I am looking for is the ability for a web written in .Net 2.0 to return JSON objects.  In other words, I don't want to serialize objects and transmit the serialized string.

Comment: Isn't JSON serialized by its nature? Javascript Serialized Object Notation(?)