# $.ajax POST to my webservice works fine but GET requests fail with error 405 Method not allowed

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services

For a while now, I've been using web services regardless of the purpose with the jquery $.ajax type: "POST". It has always gotten the job done so I never really looked into using type: "GET". I just tested "GET" out today because this plugin I'm using (EXT Gantt) requires GET and I got this Method Not Allowed (405) error in Firebug. I think I need to enable my webservice to accept GET requests. How do I do that?

Interface:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
List<Task> GetAllTasks();

[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
List<Dependency> GetAllDependencies();
```

Class:

```
[DataContract]
public class Task
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string StartDate { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string EndDate { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int PercentDone { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public bool IsLeaf { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Responsible { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Duration { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Dependency
{
    [DataMember]
    public int From { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int To { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Type { get; set; }
}
```

Methods:

```
    public List<Task> GetAllTasks()
    {

        List<Task> Tasks = new List<Task>()
        {

        };

        Task temp = new Task();

        temp.Id = 0;
        temp.Name = "Planning";
        temp.StartDate = "2010-01-06T00:00:00";
        temp.EndDate = "2010-01-21T00:00:00";
        temp.PercentDone = 40;
        temp.ParentId = null;
        temp.IsLeaf = false;
        temp.Responsible = "John Doe";
        temp.Duration = 0;
        Tasks.Add(temp);

        return Tasks;
    }

    public List<Dependency> GetAllDependencies()
    {
        List<Dependency> Dependencies = new List<Dependency>()
        {

        };

        Dependency temp = new Dependency();
        temp.From = 11;
        temp.To = 12;
        temp.Type = 2;
        Dependencies.Add(temp);

        return Dependencies;
    }
```

Javascript/Ajax: (again, this works perfectly when using type: "POST")

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    async: false,
    url: "Services/ProjectService.svc/GetAllDependencies",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) { }

});
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    async: false,
    url: "Services/ProjectService.svc/GetAllTasks",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) { }

});
```

Web.Config

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ProjectScheduler.Services.ProjectServiceBehavior" name="ProjectScheduler.Services.ProjectService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="http" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="ProjectScheduler.Services.IProjectService">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>

  <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
          <binding name="webBinding">
              <security mode="Transport">
              </security>
          </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>

<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="http">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ProjectScheduler.Services.ProjectServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944678/making-a-wcf-web-service-work-with-get-requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing the interface to

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method="GET")]
List<Task> GetAllTasks();

[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method="GET")]
List<Dependency> GetAllDependencies();
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you very very much! <3