# WCF receiving data over querystring

Tags: wcf, signalr

I am looking to integrate SignalR (.net 4.0) and Sharepoint 2010 (.net 3.5 together).

For this to work, I need a WCF server, which can recieve data posted over a querystring. What would be my best WCF option here in terms of binding? I need to post data over a querystring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've actually never head of anyone doing that. Is there a reason you *have* to use WCF? I would think something like ASP.NET MVC 4's Web API would work better.

If you are using the query string, that means it isn't SOAP, and so you can't use the `basicHttpBinding` or `wsHttpBinding`.

`webHttpBinding` might work for you. And depending on how it is hosted, you might see if there is a current web Request object you can get at.

---

Edit:

Actually, this might help too: [Making a WCF Web Service work with GET requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944678/making-a-wcf-web-service-work-with-get-requests)

And with webHttpBinding, you can specify a URL Template like this:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/url/{one}?two={two}&three={three}")]
object GetStuff(string one, int two, string three);
```

assuming you know all the query string parameters.