# How to call WCF svc with URL and parameters as a GET

Tags: wcf, url, get, svc

I have a simple WCF I am working on. I am used to .asmx files, web methods and SOAP but switching it up now. Got it working in .aspx page with a script manager and ServiceReference like below

```
<asp:ServiceReference Path="~/MyTest.svc" />
```

A coworker now needs it so he can call it in an iOS app (don't know much about that) but he says he needs to call it with the URL passing the parameters as a GET. Can you please tell me how to alter the .svc file to make that possible?

Many thanks!

Comment: This previous post might help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944678/making-a-wcf-web-service-work-with-get-requests/962096#962096