# WCF service reference not including binding and client endpoint

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I'm following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/962096/1080957) from a different question, trying to get my WCF service to only handle GET requests. I've added the `[WebGet]` to my operation, added an endpoint behavior with the `<webHttp />`, changed my default endpoint to use said behavior, and changed the default endpoint's binding to `webHttpBinding`.

web.config's system.servicemodel looks like:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
    multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

  <services>
    <service name="TestServiceLibrary.TestService">
      <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior"
         address=""
         binding="webHttpBinding"
         contract="TestServiceLibrary.ITestService" />
      <endpoint 
         address="mex" 
         binding="mexHttpBinding" 
         contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

This makes my service callable like: `TestService.svc/GetData?value=x` and that works great. Now I want to add a Service Reference to a client project. When I do that, the client project's app.config file does not get the binding and client endpoint configured. If I remove my behavior `webBehavior` above, change the default endpoint binding back to `wsHttpBinding`, and re-add the client's service reference - the client binding and endpoint are added successfully but I've lost GET support.

I realize I could leave the default endpoint using `wsHttpBinding` and add an endpoint with a different address set to binding `webHttpBinding` and a behavior with `<webHttp />`, but I would really like the client app to be using GET.

EDIT:

I'm also interested in why the config fails to update in this situation. I'm wanting to allow consumption of this service to be low-friction (add the service reference through visual studio and then start making calls), so manually setting up the client config file is not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this configuration below. I have not tested it but it should work fine. Also, I would suggest to make the client yourself using [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576141%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Note that `ISampleService` interface (in your case `TestServiceLibrary.ITestService`) and all datacontracts that are referenced by this interface should be in separate assembly which is referenced as dll by service and client.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <client>
        <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" address="url_to_TestService.svc" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="TestServiceLibrary.ITestService" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="webBehavior">
                <webHttp />
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know this is going to sound picky, but I'm really wanting it to be a low-friction ordeal to consume this service, and having to manually set-up the config file is going to be too much to ask of some of the parties that want to use this. I guess I should revise my question to include that I'm also interested in a reason as to why adding a service reference through Visual Studio doesn't include the config in this situation.

Comment: If you implement wcf client yourself (like I suggested) you could also set all these settings in code.

Comment: sorry, but I am really trying to avoid any manual repeated client configurations like that - even if it is in code. I'm having a hard time moving on this point since Visual Studio handles the configuration so gracefully in one case and then not at all in another.