# Binding post/get request to wcf service with complex object parameter (like mvc)

Tags: c#, wcf

```
public class User {
    public string UserName{get;set;}
    public string Password{get;set;}
    public string FirstName{get;set;}
    public string LastName{get;set;}
}

// WCF service
public interface IUserService {
    void SaveUser(User user);
}
```

Can I bind Post/Get request to IUserService.SaveUser service?
Something like:

`http://localhost:8080/UserService.svc/SaveUser/?UserName=bla&Password=bla&FirstName=bla`

I know it is possible by passing JSON, but I want to pass simple get/post as the above.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making a WCF Web Service work with GET requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944678/making-a-wcf-web-service-work-with-get-requests)

Comment: @KajalSinha it is not, I am dealing here with complex ibjects