# WCF/HTTP Post Web Service

Tags: web-services, wcf

Morning,

I have built a WCF Web Service that is in my Azure Cloud and works perfectly fine from the point of view using the web service within an application to send XML to the service.

However I am concerned some of the providers that need to send to my web service may not have the expertise to do use it in any other way other than HTTP POST.

My only experience of HTTP POST was creating a .asmx Web Service a while ago  that they then fire a query on a web string http://myservice/service.asmx?this=???&that=????&xml=???? .

Is there anyway I can configure my WCF Web Service to allow this?

I program in VB.NET but any sort of resource to assist would be fantastic.

Cheers,

James

Comment: You mean to say, Data goes as a querystring?

Comment: Hi, correct.

I wish in the instances of the providers not having the skill set to use the WCF and integrate it properly and just be able to fire in using a query string.

How feasible is this?

Comment: When you fire a query string call then you make an HTTP GET request. I think the following question can be of help for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944678/making-a-wcf-web-service-work-with-get-requests