# Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service - WCF

Tags: web-services, wcf, rest, web-config

I am trying to access a method within my wcf service through a url. I have followed many guides on how to hook up REST with wcf and access a method through a get. I get the following error

> Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service.

I know this has to do with my `web.config` being incorrect however, I have matched my service behavior configuration correctly. What am I missing here? Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Developer1.Core.Service.Developer1Service"
               behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior" >
        <endpoint 
            address="ws" 
            binding="wsHttpBinding"  
            contract="Developer1.Core.ServiceContracts.IDeveloper1Service" />
        <endpoint 
            address="" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior"
            binding="webHttpBinding"
            contract="Developer1.Core.ServiceContracts.IDeveloper1Service" />
        <endpoint 
            address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" 
            contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" 
            multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

Seems the error occurs after I have added behavior name="MyServiceBehavior".

This is what I am trying to accomplish [Making a WCF Web Service work with GET requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944678/making-a-wcf-web-service-work-with-get-requests)

SOLVED!!!

I solved the issue seems I had to do what i was doing within a service library instead of an application. So now I am handling REST with my wcf Library and the other methods are handled within my WCF Application. Seems app config and web config differ in a way. Then I went to solution properties and selected to start multiple projects at once. Now i can hit methods with get requests within the library and the application runs all the other methods that arent dealing with HTTP protocal. My solution has a WCF Library and WCF Application within it. The Application uses web.config and the library uses app.config. following this article http://weblogs.asp.net/kiyoshi/wcf-using-webhttpbinding-for-rest-services works with the App config. My WCF application then inherits from my service file within my Library and does not contain any extra service methods, it just runs the methods within my WCF Library. But the Library is set up to handle HTTP requests. Probably not the correct solution but it works for me.

Comment: Does the endpoint you are connecting to use http or https protocol?

Comment: This is a standard wcf service if I need to add another configuration setting. That may be the issue. The endpoint/method is listening for a http request by using the [WebGet] attribute however, I can't even start the service with the web config set up this way currently. I am new to using REST with wcf services.