# WCF service reference GET request

Tags: c#, wcf, http-get

I add WCF service as service reference on my project and try to call get methods. I got error "(405) Method Not Allowed." how I can modify the request verb from POST to GET.

```
MyServiceClient client = new MyServiceClient();
var testObj = client.GetCategories();
```

Comment: This is a server side error, please add your server side service code

Comment: This similar question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944678/making-a-wcf-web-service-work-with-get-requests