# Consuming WCF REST service in multiple ways (.Net, plain XML)

Tags: wcf, web-services, rest, soap

I have become quite frustrated of WCF as I just want to use this simple scenario:

1. Provide a webservice using REST, with a UriTemplate like `/method/{param1}/{param2}/` and a 3th parameter that is sent to the service as XML as POST data.
2. Use just plain XML, no SOAP overhead.
3. Be able to generate a proxy in Visual Studio so a .Net using client can easily use the service (don't care about SOAP overhead here).

I can create 1. and 2. but no way I can use 3. I tried adding both `webHttpBinding` and `basicHttpBinding` endpoints in my services config; I fooled around with the `<services/>` tag, but I just can't get this working. What am I missing here?!

N.B. I checked out this article: [REST / SOAP endpoints for a WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186631/rest-soap-endpoints-for-a-wcf-service) but nothing what is described there seems to work here?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot generate a client proxy for a webHttpBinding and basicHttpBinding uses SOAP.  There is no way around this.  The question you are referring to enables both bindings.  You cannot cherry-pick the features you like from each binding.

However, why would you want to create a client proxy?  Using the Microsoft.Http library, calling your service is as simple as,

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var content = HttpContent.Create(myXmlDocument);
client.Post("http://example.org/param1/param2",content)
```

Comment: I want VS to handle generating the entity-types etc. I managed to get something working using a basicHttpBinding for REST and a wsHttpBinding for SOAP.

Comment: In the WCF REST Start Kit there is a function called "Paste XML as Type" that allows you to generate classes based on returned XML that is in the clipboard.

Comment: Yes, I saw, but it's not an internal API. .Net based customers should just be able to plug their application in, and a service reference is by far the most easy.

Comment: If you use WCF Data Services (aka Astoria) in .Net 4 and VS2010 you will be able to "Add Service Reference" to it.  I don't agree with the practice, but people want to do it.