# Real world example wcf with rest and soap end points

Tags: wcf, rest, soap, .net-4.0

I've been looking around for good wcf samples which expose both WCF and REST endpoints with end to end examples and I am having a bit of trouble finding anything concrete. There are a lot of samples which say you can do this or you could do that, but nothing that really seems to bring it all together.

For instance, I'm looking for something that brings together suggestions on uri's you should use to avoid problems (both for the services and data contracts), where to place your xsd's, whether its worth trying to use the same server end point for both rest and soap, versioning and generally best practices when using WCF with rest and soap in an enterprise situation.

Cheers 
Anthony

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186631/rest-soap-endpoints-for-a-wcf-service) is a popular stack overflow question on the subject.  It is based on .Net 3.5 though.  I have not seen many samples relating to .Net 4 yet.

However, IMHO I would avoid this trap like the plague.  Doing a good API is difficult, SOAP APIs and REST apis are very different and despite what the marketing material claims, you can't just twiddle some config files, add some attribute dust and convert between the two.

Pick the one architectural style that suits your needs and **do it well**.

Comment: Cool thanks for the advice... That being the case do you know of any really good end to end examples of WCF using SOAP APIs and anther seperate one using REST APIs??

Answer (score 0):

[NerdDinner.com](http://www.nerddinner.com) : NerdDinner uses WCF Data Services, which is a great way to correctly implement RESTful services on top of WCF. The reason I am point to that, and not WCF data services directly is because it is a public website and you can use it.