# How to configure basicHttpBinding for WCF service

Tags: wcf-binding

I have a WCF service that I'm trying to get to work with wcf, old soap and plain xml.  The service is called TestService.svc and the configuration looks like this:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
   <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="TestServiceBehavior">
     <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
     <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
   </serviceBehaviors>
   <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="poxBehavior">
     <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
   </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <services>
   <service behaviorConfiguration="TestServiceBehavior" name="TestService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="ITestService">
     <identity>
      <dns value="localhost"/>
     </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="ITestService"/>
    <endpoint address="xml" binding="webHttpBinding"  behaviorConfiguration="poxBehavior" contract="ITestService"/>
   </service>
  </services>
 </system.serviceModel>
```

I got this code from this other question:
[REST / SOAP endpoints for a WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186631/rest-soap-endpoints-for-a-wcf-service)

Now, the XML webHttpBinding seems to work well, but the wsHttpBinding and basicHttpBinding does not work very well.

I can browser to the service using:
http://localhost:8295/WCFTest/TestService.svc

I can also use that endpoint to add a service reference in an asp.net web site project and attempt to consume the service, but when I create the client:

```
TestService.TestServiceClient mytest = new TestService.TestServiceClient();
```

It says to specify an endpoint due to multiple endpoints.  I guess due to having both wsHttp and basicHttp?  How do I specify the endpoint here?

Next I try to consume the basicHttpBinding endpoint by adding a Web Reference (not service reference) to a .net 2.0 web site.  At this point I'm not able to add the reference and receive an error 400.

So next I remove the wsHttp binding and am able to add the web reference and consume the service via a .net 2.0 client.

How do I configure it so that I can use wsHttpBinding for clients that can consume normal WCF services, basicHttpBinding for clients that can only consume older non-WCF SOAP requests and still have webHttpBinding available for clients that want to consume plain xml?

Comment: http://www.codemeit.com/wcf/wcf-restful-pox-json-and-soap-coexist.html should get you through this I would think. Give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

The person who posted this link (http://www.codemeit.com/wcf/wcf-restful-pox-json-and-soap-coexist.html) appears to be correct. But since this question remains unanswered, I'll elaborate a bit.

If you haven't tried it, I will mention first that nowhere in your configuration do you specify an actual address for the client service to connect to.

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="TestServiceBehavior" name="TestService">
  <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="ITestService">
    <identity>
      <dns value="localhost"/>
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
  <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="ITestService"/>
  <endpoint address="xml" binding="webHttpBinding"  behaviorConfiguration="poxBehavior" contract="ITestService"/>
</service>
```

Your first endpoint has

```
<endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="ITestService">
```

Based on documentation on MSDN (found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412178%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)) and the link above, it appears that you are missing this in your service configuration

```
<host>
  <baseAddresses>
    <!-- note, choose an available port-->
    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8295/WCFTest/TestService" />
  </baseAddresses>
</host>
```

Adding that would make your service configuration look like this

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="TestServiceBehavior" name="TestService">
  <host>
    <baseAddresses>
      <!-- note, choose an available port-->
      <add baseAddress="http://localhost:81/TestService" />
    </baseAddresses>
  </host>
  <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="ITestService">
    <identity>
      <dns value="localhost"/>
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
  <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="ITestService"/>
  <endpoint address="xml" binding="webHttpBinding"  behaviorConfiguration="poxBehavior" contract="ITestService"/>
</service>
```

Adding that section will provide the address to use, while the specific endpoints will then use addresses relative to the base address provided.