# Is it possible to use both SOAP and JSON method in single WCF service?

Tags: c#, json, wcf, soap

I am new to `WCF`. I have requirement to use same `WCF for both`SOAP`and`JSON` format using post method.Is it possible or not. Please guide me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hosting WCF soap and rest endpoints side by side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366103/hosting-wcf-soap-and-rest-endpoints-side-by-side)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up two endpoints.  However, if at all possible I would advise using WebAPI for your JSON service.  WCF's DataContractJsonSerializer is rather lacking and doesn't encode things (such as dates) quite right.  You can hack in Newtonsoft's JSON.Net, e.g. http://itq.nl/replacing-wcf-datacontractjsonserializer-with-newtonsoft-jsonserializer/ but I'd only go that route if you have to.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can for sure. i did many a times.

Comment: Can you please give me some sample code for reference to check how it's work