# how does XML and Soap work with WCF?

Tags: xml, wcf, soap

I have been asked this question in interview

how does XML and Soap work with WCF ?

can any one explain this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WCF provides several options (*bindings*) for communicating between machines or processes. Some of these use a binary format (e.g. *NetTcpBinding*), whereas some of them use text over HTTP (e.g. *BasicHttpBinding* and *WsHttpBinding*).

When communicating with a WCF service over HTTP, for example using the BasicHttpBinding, you will be using SOAP, a messaging protocol which uses XML to format messages.

You can see the SOAP messages going between client and server by using the [Service Trace Viewer tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx) that comes with the [Windows SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb980924.aspx).

One advantage of WCF is that the underlying method of communication is abstracted away to a degree - you can write code to consume a WCF service without having to care about if SOAP/XML is going to be used, or binary. Of course, the actual implementation can be very important, so you still need to know what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

The question is pretty vague. Maybe these will get you started on what you're looking for?

- [REST / SOAP endpoints for a WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186631/rest-soap-endpoints-for-a-wcf-service)
- [What Is Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx)
- [search SO for xml+soap+wcf](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=soap+xml+wcf)