# ASMX to WCF migration

Tags: wcf, migration, asmx

i m new in WCF.

Currently i m trying to upgrade my current asmx service project in to WCF.
-->I developed one dummy client (windows application)  in .net 2.0.
--> Then i developed  one asmx service for that client. It works without any issue.
--> After this i upgraded current asmx project in to WCF (with backword compatibility) without changing method definations.
--> Now m trying to access WCF service methods by changing URL from clients app.config file.
--> When client calls service methods it goes to correct method on server but server taking all parameters as 0 . Also client getting null even after server returning valid result.

Please help ...

Thanks

Comment: can you show you service code and config?

Comment: Please find the answer below @vikaspalav

http://stackoverflow.com/a/30482561/4944540

Answer (score 0):

Your code may be very helpful.

Also, please start from verify that your parameter names on the methods **are same (include case)** as in your service contract definition.