# Soap and Rest Webservices

Tags: asp.net, .net, rest, soap

I need to give a demo on the working of Soap and Rest(practical example). Could anyone help please and suggest an example using .net frame work or any other suitable ways.

Let me put it this way "I want to implement Soap and rest web services in asp.net. I need the required steps to do it"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple example that I usually use is the calculator service. [This](http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2008/11/25/my-durable-wcf-restful-calculator.aspx) is an example Restful implementation and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/WebServiceIntr.aspx) is the same one using SOAP.

Comment: thanks Prashant. Could you get any other examples/steps for Rest just like Soap u gave..thanks agaain!

Comment: Google around for 'RESTful examples with C#' and you will see may examples.

Answer (score 1):

Searching in internet would help you.
I wound this artticle that may help you in your presntation of pros/cons of the two.

http://geeknizer.com/rest-vs-soap-using-http-choosing-the-right-webservice-protocol/ 
or a nice presentation taken from here
http://www.slideshare.net/cesare.pautasso/rest-vs-soap-making-the-right-architectural-decision-1st-international-soa-symposium-amsterdam-october-2008-presentation

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks supersonic
those are some wonderful links u suggested, but the thing is i need to practically show with examples(in .net) i mean setting up the whole scenario and explaining in real. Besides im done with slides and theoritical explainations.

Answer (score 1):

WCF is smart. He can make us go. We need him. [REST / SOAP endpoints for a WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186631/rest-soap-endpoints-for-a-wcf-service)

Answer (score 0):

Given the fact that you're about to do a presentation, I think you want examles in terms of use cases and not technically, right?

Here are a few examples:

- Translation service
- Currency converter

Comment: No offense, but how do you want to present such a topic with this kind of background knowledge?

Comment: @Will +1 For "it's funny because it's true" but also "it hurts because it's true". :-)