# WCF web service and java web service

Tags: java, wcf, web-services

Can web service developed in **Java** can be consumed by **WCF web service** and vice versa.??

Comment: Yes they can - just expose them as REST/SOAP webservices:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186631/rest-soap-endpoints-for-a-wcf-service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Web Services are basically request/response calls through a network. The message is XML. This protocol is known as [SOAP (Simple Object Access Protocol)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP). So, you're passing XML data across the wire. WCF wouldn't care less which originating language it comes from as it only sees XML.

Alternatively, you can use HTTP request/response using [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST).

Comment: thanks.. The Elite Gentleman... since i am new to it.. can i have some document or url to read it in more depth..

Comment: What do you need to understand, SOAP, REST (link provided)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes they can, if you run into trouble and are using SOAP it will most likely be due to versions in the security headers. If so you WCF can be configured to use custom binding (Sure the same applies for java side). Rest is simpler.

Checkout http://www.soapui.org/. It is written in java and can communicate using both Rest and Soap.