# Configuring wcf rest services in web.config

Tags: wcf, rest, web-config

Where in the `web.config` should the following blocks of code go for a WCF RESTful service?

```
<endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding"contract="Wcf_Test.IMyService"    
behaviorConfiguration="httpEndpointBehavour"> 
    <identity> 
        <dns value="localhost"/> 
    <Identity>  
</endpoint>
```

and

```
<behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors> 
        <behavior name="httpBehaviour"> <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
        </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
```

and

```
    <endpointBehaviors> 
        <behavior name="httpEndpointBehavour"> 
            <webHttp />
        </behavior> 
    </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: Use wcf SVC config editor.

Answer (score 29):

In order to configure a WCF REST service, you need a few things in your web.config file

1) Declare your service and its endpoint

```
<services>
  <service name="SparqlService.SparqlService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" contract="SparqlService.ISparqlService"
              behaviorConfiguration="webHttp"/>
  </service>
</services>
```

Service name will be [project name].[service name]
Behavior configuration will be same name as the behavior you declare in the next step
Binding must be webHttpBinding because you want it as REST. If you want SOAP, you declare as basicHttpBinding
Contract is the [project name].[interface name]
Behavior configuration in the endpoint will be the name you declare in next step

2) Declare the service behavior (usually default)

```
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior" >
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
```

Behavior name can be anything, but it will be used to match BehaviorConfiguration you declared in step 1
Leave the rest alone

3) Declare your endpoint behavior

```
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webHttp">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
```

Behavior name can be anything, but it will be used to match the behaviorConfiguration in endpoint.

In the end, this is what the web.config should look like for a simple REST service:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>

    <services>
      <service name="SparqlService.SparqlService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" contract="SparqlService.ISparqlService"
                  behaviorConfiguration="webHttp"/>
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>

        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior" >
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>


        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>

      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttp">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>

    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: This post is useful to beginners. It would be better if there was explanation on bindings and their implications. Anyways, thanks.

Comment: Anything for basic HTTP binding?

Comment: Documentation in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/wcf-web-http-programming-model .

Comment: "Service name will be [project name].[service name]", That did the trick for me, awesome.

Answer (score 1):

for the rest type using WCFservice

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel> 
       <services> 
          <service>
    <--
       "place the first code snippet here "
        it will contain the endpoint details
        for WCFrestfulServices it will have 'A' ,'B' and 'C'
        that is address, binding and contract
    -->
          </service>
       </services>
       <behaviors>
       <servicebehaviours>
    <--
       "place the second code snippet"
       the name of the behavior should be the same to that of the
       behavior configuration attribute value of service tag
    -->
      </servicebehaviours>
      <endpointBehaviors>
    <--
       "place your third code snippet"
       the name of the behavior should be the same to that of the
       behavior configuration attribute value of endpoint tag
    -->
      </endpointBehaviors>
       </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel> 
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Web config changes.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfService1.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="restbehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
                  contract ="WcfService1.IBookService">          
        </endpoint>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost/bookservice"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>                
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="restbehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>   
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Interface: we have to use WebGet for httpGet / WebInvoke for HttpPost & Put & Delete.

```
 [ServiceContract]
    public interface IBookService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet]
        List<BOOK> GetBooksList();

        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "Book/{id}")]
        BOOK GetBookById(string id);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "AddBook/{name}")]
        void AddBook(string name);
}
```

Ref : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/571813/A-Beginners-Tutorial-on-Creating-WCF-REST-Services