# Hitting function but not getting the return value

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, postman

I've created a simple WCF service for an application that I'm currently working on using DevExtreme.

To test my service, I use Postman, provided from the google play store thing.

The server starts up fine. If I debug my function `GetLogins()`I can see that Postman invokes this function, but I'm not receiving the return value.

**IService.cs:**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/logins")]
    List<Login> GetLogins();
}
```

**Service.cs:**

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class Service : IService
{
    //Returns all Logins
    public List<Login> GetLogins()
    {
        var list = DAO.Instance.Login.ToList();
        return list;
    }
}
```

**App.config:**

```
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
<services>
  <service name="HourRegistrationWCF.Service">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/HourRegistrationWCF/Service/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <!-- Service Endpoints -->
    <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
    <endpoint address=""
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              contract="HourRegistrationWCF.IService"
              behaviorConfiguration="REST">
      <!-- 
          Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
          identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
          automatically.
      -->
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
    <!-- The Metadata Exchange endpoint is used by the service to describe itself to clients. -->
    <!-- This endpoint does not use a secure binding and should be secured or removed before deployment -->
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="REST">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
      set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True" />
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
      set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
      to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true"/>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

I can't seem to find the problem.

**Postman response**

[image]

Comment: If you put debugger at GetLogins() method in server side is control flow coming there? i mean will it hit to debugger ?

Comment: @Popeye Yes it will. I can even see the 1 `Login`I have in the db. Postman just isn't receiving it.

Comment: can you check your Login class whether you have defined it as Data Contract and fields of it as Data Members .

Comment: Excuse me for my rookie flaws, but I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: Please also check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17644392/configuring-wcf-rest-services-in-web-config for configurations, i think you are missing some behavior configurations. Check all configurations once.

Comment: I mean to say, you are returning List<Login> so Login class is your data Contract. Please check here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/664238/Understanding-Contracts-in-WCF

Comment: I tried the link you sent me, but no success. Still not getting the return value

Comment: The Login class is straight from the db, using entity framework. The strange thing is that I had this working with a previous WCF service, using the EXACT same configurations (except for the names ofcourse), so I can't see why it shouldn't work now.

Comment: @Popeye after looking at my configuration and making sure everything is fine, it's still not working.

Comment: Fixet it by turning the `ProxyCreationEnabled` to `false` in the db context. It had some problem with the serialization