# Same WCF service with different EndPoints and Different Bindings For HTTPS

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I have looked at several posts on SO which are showing how to add multiple endpoints for same service, but non of them is actually using HTTPS, which is why I am asking this question.

**What I have**

I have a web service,

```
https://portal.gov.com/us/216/_vti_bin/external/gov.svc
```

**What I want**

I want to call this web services using two different configurations, and bindings with different ENDPOINTS but SAME URL ?. (Sorry maybe I am confused with concept of EndPoints)

Here is what my web.config looks like,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Gov_ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>

      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="restBehavior">
          <webHttp defaultBodyStyle="Wrapped" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Gov_webHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="InheritedFromHost" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
      <!--<basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Gov_BasicHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="InheritedFromHost" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>-->
    </bindings>

    <services>
      <service name="Portal.WebServices.External.Gov" behaviorConfiguration="Gov_ServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="restBehavior" contract="Portal.WebServices.External.IGov" bindingConfiguration="Gov_webHttpBinding"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <!--<endpoint address="basic" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Portal.WebServices.External.IGov" bindingConfiguration="Gov_BasicHttpBinding"/>-->
      </service>
    </services>

  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

**WHERE IS THE PAIN**

IT only works until I keep basicHttpBinding commented out and it's endpoint, as soon as I include it, I get silent error.

According to this - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751515(v=vs.110).aspx

It should work, but it doesn't maybe because I am using HTTPS and adding BINDINGS tag to my web.Config

Comment: I don't think `WebHttpBinding` is consider similarly to `BasicHttpBinding` or so.When one builds a restful wcf service , needs to use `WebHttpBinding`.And no `MetaData` is exposed for consumption.

Comment: `HTTPS` is definitely not the case here, but the way you're exposing your service , i.e. the bindings combination you choose might not work side by side.Can you try removing the `WebHttpBinding` and add another `WsHttpBinding` instead to see what happens.

Comment: In case of `WebHttpBinding`  no MetaData is exposed for consumption.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14403492/cannot-process-the-message-because-the-content-type-application-json-charset-u

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh I am sorry but I don't think you understand the issue in the question, thanks for trying though.

Comment: I can understand your problem, but are you considering my inputs?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is impossible. You can't apply two different bindings with exactly the same Endpoint. If you try to read again your reference [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751515(v=vs.110).aspx) it is clear that the sample has two different endpoints :

First address is http://localhost/servicemodelsamples/service.svc and the second
is http://localhost/servicemodelsamples/service.svc/secure. These two endpoints are different to each other but share with same contract.

The second endpoint is just relative to the base address http://localhost/servicemodelsamples/service.svc.

I hope this make your mind clear about binding and endpoint.