# Why isn't this WCF service accessible via JSON Ajax?

Tags: ajax, wcf, json

I have a WCF service that needs to be called via SOAP (working) and via JSON (not working).

My C# code:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string Foo();
}

public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string Foo()
    {
        return "woohooo";
    }
}
```

And here's my config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>

    <services>
      <service name="Service1">
        <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="DummyService.IService1"/>
        <endpoint address="json" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior" contract="DummyService.IService1"/>
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="jsonBehavior">
          <enableWebScript/>
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

And here's my Javascript:

```
$.getJSON("/Service1.svc/Foo")
    .success(function (result) {
        alert("success! " + result);
    })
    .fail(function (result) {
        console.log("failed!");
        console.log(result);
    });
```

The response I get is "400 Bad Request". What am I doing wrong? I've followed the advice in [REST / SOAP endpoints for a WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186631/rest-soap-endpoints-for-a-wcf-service), but it still-a-no-worksies. :-) Help!

Comment: Have you looked at what's going on through fiddler?

Comment: Yep. Fiddler just shows a 400 Bad Request.

Comment: I just updated the post to include the whole config file.

Comment: Forgive me if you've done this: In the service behaviour, set IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults to true. In fiddler, look at the Inspectors tab, an in the bottom panel click on TextView. This gives you a wealth of information.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this tonight and let you know the results.

Comment: If you look at the config file, you'll see I have already set IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults to true. I'll check the inspectors tab in Fiddler and let you know the results. Thanks for all your help so far, I feel like we're close to fixing this.

Comment: I ended up getting this working via Garret's answer. Thanks for your help in debugging this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try including the endpoint address in the service URL. Something like:

```
$.getJSON("/Service1.svc/json/Foo")
```

Also, you should enable [WCF tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) to see what error is being returned. You will need the [Service Trace Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx) to view the log information.

**UPDATE:**

Below is an example using your code that works.

The configuration file contains

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>

    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="jsonServiceBehavior" name="DummyService.Service1">
        <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="DummyService.IService1"/>
        <endpoint address="json" 
                  behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior" 
                  binding="webHttpBinding" contract="DummyService.IService1"/>
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="jsonBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>

      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="jsonServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I created an empty web project and added the following HTML page to test the service.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.getJSON("/Service1.svc/json/Foo")
            .success(function (result) {
                alert("success! " + result);
            })
            .fail(function (result) {
                console.log("failed!");
                console.log(result);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>    

</body>
</html>
```

And my `Service1.svc` has the following:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Service="DummyService.Service1" %>
```

Comment: Tried including the endpoint address, still no luck; result is 400 (Bad Format).

Comment: Have you enabled tracing? What is the exact WCF exception? Did you check the event log? You can also try using fiddler to trace the call.

Comment: I haven't. I'll try that tonight.

Comment: Just saw your update. It works! Thank you so much, I was just about to rewrite the WCF service as a REST controller, which would have been costly. This preserves my current code, and makes my AJAX workable. Awesome! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking it's because the URL you are using is an absolute URL, not a relative one.

If you are running this in the ASP.NET debugger, the service would be available on the following address:

```
http://localhost:52200/Web/Service1.svc
```

Because you are preceeding the URL with a forward slash, the service query is actually being sent to

```
http://localhost:52200/Service1.svc
```

So you need to pass in the appropriate **relative** address. If your service and the script file are in the same directory, change it to:

```
$.getJSON("./Service1.svc/Foo")
```

Comment: No luck. The service and script file are in the same directory, and I'm running this under Visual Studio debugger. Looking at the request in Chrome dev tools, it says, "GET http://localhost:4618/Service1.svc/Foo 400 (Bad Request)"

Comment: @Judah - And what's the request path of the page that is hosting the script?

Comment: OK, I'm convinced that that isn't the problem

Answer (score 1):

Try taking out the `<webHttp />` element from the endpoint behavior.

I have a web service that is invoked by Ajax, and it doesn't have this element.

When I tried putting the element in, it stopped working.

(Admittedly, this was to do with not recognizing the date formats, so it's not an exact match for your problem).

Comment: Oops, that was accidental left-over from testing. But still, if I take it out, still no luck, still getting the 400 error (Bad Request)

Comment: I noticed I didn't paste my whole config file. Can you look at it again? Does it look good to you?

Answer (score 1):

(My third answer. I know that ONE of these answers is going to be right :-)

Try setting `aspNetCompatibilityEnabled` to true on the serviceHostingEnvironment.

```
   <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

This is just a guess. When I turn this off on my implementation the call still arrives, but `HttpContext.Current` returns NULL.