# Consume WCF Service in json format

Tags: php, asp.net, json

i have created WCF Service, i want to consume WCF Service in PHP with json format. i don't have any idea how to call WCF Service in PHP.

Comment: This really depends on how you built your WCF Service. You could write it to be [RESTful](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee391967.aspx) - then it's as simple as calling a URL

Answer (score 0):

As prescott said - if it's a restful service then you are calling a url.

If the service is using soap and wsdl (not JSON as stated) [Using WCF Services with PHP](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2007/09/17/using-wcf-services-with-php.aspx) has a simple example.

If your service is actually returning SOAP and you /want/ it to return JSON, either re-jig the service to use [Content Negotiation](http://blog.malevy.net/2011/06/messin-with-wcf-web-api-part-ii-content.html) via the WcfWebApi or [setup multiple endpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186631/rest-soap-endpoints-for-a-wcf-service)

Hopefully one of these options will help you.