# WCF REST 404 when trying GET

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest, wcf-rest

I keep getting a 404 on a very basic WCF service that I want to expose via REST - I'm trying to access it by going to this URL when debugging:
http://localhost:62888/Service1.svc/xml/data/test

I can view the service info at http://localhost:62888/Service1.svc but not at http://localhost:62888/Service1.svc/xml

I'm using .Net 4 and its a WCF Service Application project. I tried debugging with Cassini as well as IIS Express

**Web.Config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Service1">
        <!-- address is relative-->
        <endpoint address="xml" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="webHttp" contract="IService1" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttp">
          <webHttp />         <!-- enables RESTful in conjunction with webHttpBinging -->
          <enableWebScript /> <!-- allows ajax communication -->
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

**IService.cs**

```
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

namespace CI.WcfRestTest
{
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/data/{id}")]
        string GetData(string id);
    }
}
```

**Service1.svc.cs**

```
namespace CI.WcfRestTest
{
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string GetData(string id)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", id);
        }
    }
}
```

I've read a bunch of articles on the subject including this one [REST / SOAP endpoints for a WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/q/186631/71904) . Perhaps there's something in Cassini or my machine config thats goofing things up? I've read of issues with Windows Vista, but I'm on Windows 7 Pro. Perhaps it has something to do with a WCF Service Application as opposed to a WCF Service Library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be as simple as having the wrong service name in your config.

Currently, you have:

```
<services>
  <service name="Service1">
```

**BUT:** this needs to be the **fully qualified** service name - including any namespaces!

So try this instead:

```
 <services>
    <service name="CI.WcfRestTest.Service1">
       <!-- address is relative-->
       <endpoint address="xml" 
                 binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="webHttp" 
                 contract="CI.WcfRestTest.IService1" />
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    </service>
</services>
```

Just replace `Service1` with `CI.WcfRestTest.Service1` (and the same for the contract). Does that solve you problem??

Comment: Thanks! That worked (facepalm), I also had to remove the <enableWebScript /> since that doesn't work with UriTemplate