# wcf service - test with url to call method does not work and remotely

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wcf, wcf-client

I created a WCF service that returns a line of text and using a client application tested it and was able to retrieve the line of text. I thought that if I put the entire url in a browser that includes the method that returns the line of text it would work but instead I get a 400 not found error.
For example the main url is :

```
http://localhost/DataAdmin/GService.svc?wsdl
```

So when I try to past the following in a browser it does not work:

```
http://localhost/DataAdmin/GService.svc/RetrieveData?inputText=test
```

Oh, the reason for this is that I am trying to test it remotely. I want an app to be able to call the service from another server/domain.
I'm thinking it has something perhaps to do with the config files. Here is the config file of my service project.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
 <behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not as simple as that. WCF works with the SOAP protocol, you can't 'just' pass the method name and the value in the Url.

You can use a Restfull-API, I am referring you to [this awsome post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186631/rest-soap-endpoints-for-a-wcf-service) that tells all about it in a simple and concise manner.