# Expose a WCF (Azure)Cloud Service as both SOAP and REST

Tags: wcf, web-services, rest, soap, azure

I am already aware of this link : [REST / SOAP endpoints for a WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186631/rest-soap-endpoints-for-a-wcf-service)

I do understand in some point, that i need to add those behaviors and bindings to a new endpoint for the service to be RESTful.

I am a bit confused though in where to add these endpoints.

Explaining: 
I currently have a Service which is WCF SOAP based, and is published to Azure Cloud Services

I have a website and a client that reference to that URL of the published service.

Now, in order to make it RESTful, do i need to edit the web.config file in the Service, and then re-publish the service to the cloud? (Reference of website,client stays as is)
Or also do I need to edit the app.config files of the WebSite and the Client?
(endpoints for Rest, and having two in total)

Comment: web.config as I read on the web, has to do with hosting in IIS if I am not mistaken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. I believe you do.

The service configuration is normally controller either through code or web.config so to add an endpoint you will need to change your service and/or configuration and re-publish.

depending on how you configure the additional endpoint your role configuration might need to change as well, i.e. if you need another TCP port opened.

Comment: "Change my service", do you mean by just adding WebGets and WebInvokes?