# WCF RESTful - Best Approach needed

Tags: .net, wcf, rest

What would be the best method to create a WCF Service which is RESTful?

That is, need to create a service - that can be consumed by both .Net clients as well as Java / Android Clients.

I would need a service which can accept a single value and return a single value;

Then, a single value and return multiple values;

Then, a single value and return a set of records (dataset);

Then, can accept multiple values and return all the 3;

Please let me know the best method for this.

Comment: Don't know what "best method" means but you might start here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186631/rest-soap-endpoints-for-a-wcf-service?rq=1

Comment: You can also think on using Web API instead of wcf as it is much better platform for RESTful service development.