# transition from WCF too WCF RESTful

Tags: c#, wpf, web-services, wcf, rest

I have a Normal WCF Service and a WPF application that obviously calls data from that service. I have an issue now where a mobile web application came into play and also needs to call the same data on the same service, and with a little Googling I have seen with web application you will need to use a WCF RESTful to access the data. ( I can be wrong :) )

Can anyone advice me on what or how I can make my service so without changing any big chunk of coding in my WPF application and give access to data for the mobile application?

Comment: You can add a rest endpoint to your existing WCF service, as explained in [the duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186631/rest-soap-endpoints-for-a-wcf-service).

Answer (score -1):

Look at this post, it should contain everything you need to accomplish your requirement.

[REST / SOAP endpoints for a WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186631/rest-soap-endpoints-for-a-wcf-service)

You can add a second endpoint in order to expose REST behaviour while keeping the SOAP interface letting you keep the WPF app without changes.

Comment: Link-only answers aren't answers. Include all relevant details in your post, or flag to close as duplicate.

Comment: I don't believe you can just mark it as duplicate. User has a requirement and doesn't know how to handle. Just answering "it's a duplicate, google is your friend" doesn't help.

Comment: That's not what duplicates do, they point you to a specific question.