# What's the easiest way to add a RESTFul interface to an existing ASMX (SOAP based) service?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, soap, asmx

I am working with an existing ASMX (SOAP) based service.
I have been tasked with extending the service to support a RESTFul based interface.

Is the easiest approach to convert the service to a WCF service with the interface definitions decorated with [WebInvoke(Method="")]?

Can someone point me to an example?

Thanks,
JB

Comment: Possible duplicate of [REST / SOAP endpoints for a WCF service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186631/rest-soap-endpoints-for-a-wcf-service)

Comment: Actually, I know how to expose REST/SOAP endpoints on a WCF service. The question is "What is the best way to extend an ASMX (SOAP) based service to expose a RESTFul interface.

Comment: ha. guess I should read more carefully!

Comment: `ASMX` is legacy and should not be used. Also, `ASMX` is **SOAP-only** - there's no way to "extend it" to support REST - it's SOAP and SOAP-only. The only viable option would be to create a **new** REST service, e.g. using WCF with REST or by using Web API, and surface some of the same data. However: REST is **resource-based** while SOAP is **method-based** so there's usually no 1:1 mapping, really .....

Comment: Thanks marc_s/DrewJordan