# Rest service .net using config

Tags: asp.net, .net, rest, wcf, restful-architecture

What is the best way to create an .net rest service including the endpoint, operationcontract and data binding from a config file?

The config file includes for instance:

- Endpoint:
  www.cars.com
- OperationContract

  - GetCarFuel
  - GetCarHorsePower
- Data binding:

  - GetCarFuel should use or return the dataContract CarFuel
  - The same for GetCarHorsePower

Comment: Just google it:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/803009/Configure-WCF-Service-to-REST or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186631/rest-soap-endpoints-for-a-wcf-service or http://www.topwcftutorials.net/2013/09/simple-steps-for-restful-service.html

Comment: Thank you for the link. I read the article but the author didn't use a config to generate the endpoint and operation contracts.