# How to consume wcf in .net core without adding service reference?

Tags: wcf, asp.net-core

I want to consume a WCF service in my .NET Core application without adding service reference?

I am able to consume WCF by installing WCF connected service and adding service reference but I don't want to add any service reference.

Comment: Create it by hand? :P

Comment: Use ChannelFactory<T> from System.ServiceModel https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/tree/master/src/System.Private.ServiceModel/src/System/ServiceModel

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to the follow link. It has some minors issues, but is easy to fix.

[Calling Web Method Without a Service Reference](https://www.diogonunes.com/blog/calling-a-web-method-in-c-without-a-service-reference/)

Answer (score 1):

if you are using wcf service then you can expose it as a restful service. then you can simply consume it. actully i have been use it for many years and its been really useful.
here you can read more about that: [REST / SOAP endpoints for a WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186631/rest-soap-endpoints-for-a-wcf-service)

Comment: i want to consume in .net core framework not in 4.5 or 4.6

Comment: i don't get it. so just consume it. i did a same many time. wrote restful wcf service then consume it any where you like!

Answer (score -2):

you can create a service proxy using svcutil.exe and use the proxy class as a reference.

here is a sample:

```
SvcUtil.exe http://www.temperatureservice.com:8080/TemperatureService.svc /ser:DataContractSerializer /s /language:cs  /out:TemperatureServiceProxy.cs  /n:*,WCF.Client.Proxies.Proxy
```

It will generate TemperatureServiceProxy.cs file, include this file in your project and create a service client by referencing this file.

Comment: *How to consume wcf in .net core without adding service reference?*, and  *I want to consume a wcf service in my core application without adding service reference*, and *I don't want to add any service reference*. The OP has specifically stated **three times** in their question that they do not want to use a service reference. Yet your solution is to use a service reference. Did you actually read the question?