# WCF REST Endpoint

Tags: c#, json, wcf, soap

I am developing a WCF and I want it to be called by both ways SOAP/REST.

Now I am able to get response by SOAP but unable to call the same WCF by JSON request.

**IService1.cs**

```
[OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(CustomException))]  
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/Validateuser",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml | WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml | WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    ResponsetoCustomer Validateuser(ValidateCustomerInput validate);
```

**Web.config**

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="TractorMitraIntegration.IService1"  behaviorConfiguration="ServBehave">
    <!--Endpoint for SOAP-->
    <endpoint
       address="soapService"
        binding="basicHttpBinding"
        contract="TractorMitraIntegration.IService1"/>
    <!--Endpoint for REST-->
    <endpoint
      address="XMLService"
       binding="webHttpBinding"
       behaviorConfiguration="restPoxBehavior"
       contract="TractorMitraIntegration.IService1"/>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServBehave">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
<endpointBehaviors>
    <!--Behavior for the REST endpoint for Help enability-->
    <behavior name="restPoxBehavior">
      <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
</protocolMapping>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
```

Below error I am facing,

> Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/json' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json":

```
<behavior name="restPoxBehavior">
   <webHttp helpEnabled="true" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" />
</behavior>
```

Comment: Done as you suggest but no luck.                                                
HTTP/1.1 415 Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/json' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'.
Cache-Control: private
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpcSW5wcm9ncmVzc1xUcmFjdG9yTWl0cmFJbnRlZ3JhdGlvblxUcmFjdG9yTWl0cmFJbnRlZ3JhdGlvblxTZXJ2aWNlMS5zdmNcVmFsaWRhdGV1c2Vy?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 14 Jul 2017 07:27:55 GMT
Content-Length: 0

Comment: You may need to research on WebContentTypeMapper, I guess. If it was the problem of ajax failure, you should pay attention on json data, it should be stringified.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot support both soap and rest for the same endpoint. 
See this [REST / SOAP endpoints for a WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186631/rest-soap-endpoints-for-a-wcf-service) for how to.